# Custom Razor HTML Markup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm looking into creating a custom helper to do the following:

```
<a href="controller/"> <strong>Item</strong> </a>
```

I know that @Html.RouteLink(...) will handle the anchor for you but I wanted to insert the `"<strong> </strong>"` tag to it.

Other than to write a custom method to manipulate the string, I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use `new { @class = "myClass" }` as parameters to the helper and apply css to the link to make it bold.
2. Manually create the anchor's URL (`<a href="@Url.RouteUrl(...)`) to the path you want using `Url.RouteUrl`

Comment: Didn't know about RouteUrl (New at mvc). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your extension of ActionLink. Look at [this article](http://agilefutures.com/index.php/2009/06/actionimage-aspnet-mvc). the author wrote about extending to have Img link, but you can get the idea and info to do your own extension

Answer (score 0):

I would create an anchor with a class so you put your styling in CSS instead of making the html heavier and define the style of the page.